# Is there a way to not inherit "virtualness" of a function in a subclass?

Tags: c++, virtual

Is it possible in C++ to have a class override a virtual function, but only have virtual dispatch when the function is called through the superclass (ie. not when it is called on something statically typed as the subclass)? I know this isn't what happens, but is there any way to achieve something close?

The reason for wanting this is that I have two classes which both expose a `flush()` function. The vast majority of the time in my program, I am calling `flush()` directly on a subclass object that I know the type of, so I don't need virtual dispatch. However I want to add a superclass into the mix so that very infrequently I can pass a reference to an instance of either one of the classes into a `doSomethingThenFlush()` function, which would call `flush()` virtually.

I know I could use templates instead of virtual functions, and I know I could have two different functions (eg. `flushVirtual()` which just called `flushNonVirtual()`, and call `flushNonVirtual()` everywhere I don't need virtual dispatch). But these both seem a bit like throwing code at a problem which is largely syntactical. Is there any more elegant way to achieve this?

Perhaps more importantly, does anyone know why virtualness is inherited in C++?

```
struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base(){}
  virtual void func();
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  void func(){}
};

void callVirtually(Base &base)
{
  base.func();//this will use virtual dispatch
}

void callStatically(Derived &derived)
{
  derived.func();//I don't want/need this to use virtual dispatch
}

int main()
{
  Derived derived;
  callVirtually(derived);
  callStatically(derived);
}
```

Comment: Hooray, C++ half-baked object model.

Comment: @David How is that relevant to the question at hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++03, no.

As others said, it is a compiler optimization (and a frequently used one) to de-virtualize he call whenever it can assess that the runtime type of the object.

However, in C++0x we get two new keywords: `override` and `final` and both can be applied to member functions (`final` can also be applied to a class).

- `override`: specify that this function overrides a virtual function in a base class, useful to get warned when this is not the case
- `final`: specify that this function (virtual) cannot be overriden in children classes.

Your class would thus become:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
  void func() final {}
};
```

*Note: using **final** does not mandate that the compiler devirtualize function calls (from the Standard point of view), but any compiler worth its salt should do so.*

Answer (score 8):

Virtualness is inherited because you don't know if someone is going to derive further from your `Derived`. Someone could just as well make a `MoreDerived` which could be passed to a function expecting a `Derived&`, and they'd be sad when they found that it was `Derived`'s versions of all your virtual functions were bieng called instead of `MoreDerived`'s.

If you mean that you won't ever inherit from `Derived` so you don't want to pay for a virtual function call, then you're out of luck, because C++ provides no way to promise that you won't ever inherit from a class, which would be necessary to do what you are wanting.

Comment: But in this instance, I decided not to make `Derived::func()` virtual (well, I tried to) so I want to pay the price. In my actual project, `Derived` will never be subclassed and I'm fine with that.

Comment: @Karu C++ provides no way to promise that no class will inherit from `Derived`, which would be necessary for it to do what you want it to do, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It's not necessary, it just means that people expecting `Derived::func()` to behave virtually would be disappointed. It's exactly the same as if `func()` wasn't virtual in `Base`, or if `Base` didn't exist.

Comment: It's necessary for things to work right. What if you passed a `MoreDerived` into a function expecting a `Base&`? Which version should it call? It can't call `MoreDerived`'s because it's not virtual.

Comment: It should call `MoreDerived::func()`, just as `callVirtually()` in my example above calls `Derived::func()`. There's no technical reason I can think of that would disallow this.

Comment: @Karu that would be what virtual functions do, but you said that you don't want to inherit the virtualness of the function beyond `Derived`. You can't have a half-virtual function.

Comment: The notion of a function being virtual is basically what I'm wondering about. You can consider the function just existing, and the _calls_ to that function as being done virtually or not. The `virtual` keyword on a function tells the compiler that calls to that function should happen virtually. Is there something incorrect about my thinking?

Comment: @Karu those few sentences aren't enough to grasp your grasp of virtual functions, but know that making a function `virtual` tells the compiler that you can't make any assumptions about pointers or references to that class when someone calls that function on one, so it has to look up the real function through a table that the object carries around. Since you could have a 500 class long chain of inheritance, you've no idea what a `Derived&` actually is behind the reference. You're wanting virtualness to stop at one class deep, but if it does then a `MoreDerived` might not even have a `func`.

Comment: @Karu hopefully someone else can explain it better than I, but trust me, it's not cleanly possible.

Answer (score 4):

In your specific example, if `callStatically` gets inlined, the compiler will probably avoid the virtual function dispatch because it can see the object's actual type (because it is a local variable).

Probably your compiler can also avoid a virtual dispatch for cases like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    callStatically() { d.func() }
private:
    Derived d;
};
```

The compiler is likely to perform this optimization whether or not `callStatically` is inlined, because it can see the actual type of the variable member.

But to my knowledge, there is no way to force the compiler to bypass the virtual call in general.

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in your question.

```
derived.func();  // no virtual dispatch
```

When you call a `virtual` function using object, there is no `virtual` dispatch. It calls the function using the static-type of the object.

`virtual` function comes into the picture only when you try to call a function using a *pointer* or a *reference*.

**Edit**: In your updated question, you are using `Derived&` to call `func()`. Calling by reference will make sure that `virtual` dispatch happens. So there is no language facility (like `final` in Java), which will stop `virtual` dispatch.

Comment: Sorry, the example was incorrect :) I've updated it to match what I actually wanted to ask.

Comment: Compiler optimizations should stop `virtual` dispatch, especially if the function call gets inlined.